Unable to proceed after "Reached target Cloud-init target
I am new to Ubuntu parallel desktop. I am having an issue when starting the desktop. It was good yesterday but today when I tried, It stuck at "[OK] Reached target Cloud-init target. " and did not move on. If anyone encountered this before and solved it. Please teach me What caused all these issues and how should I do to solve it?
Sincerely and Great Thanks,
H.

does this Server Fault Q&A help?
